# How come Rust has trouble finding transitive dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

In Rust I'm getting the error during `cargo build`:

```
 use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `tokio`
```

even though I have

```
[dependencies]
tokio-tungstenite = {version = "0.17", features = ["native-tls"]}
```

and I can see the `tokio` in the `cargo tree`

```
└── tokio-tungstenite v0.17.1
    ├── tokio v1.18.1
```

Is Rust not pulling in the transitive dependencies?  I thought it would.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. You have to add `tokio` to your dependencies for it to be available. Under the hood cargo will attempt to re-use the same `tokio` version, but it is not always possible to do so.

For example lets say your dependencies look like this:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "0.4.9"  # Depends on sap = "0.2.1"
bar = "1.2.1"  # Depends on sap = "0.9.7"
```

These two crates depend on different versions of `sap`. Since cargo is unable to find a version that both crates are happy with, it builds both. At this point it is completely ambiguous which version cargo should supply your crate.

However, you can use `*` to instead ask cargo to choose a version for you.

```
sap = "*"
```

You can read more about how versions are handled here:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html

Answer (score 2):

Cargo does pull transitive dependencies, but it doesn't mean you can access them. You have to explicitly declare that you want it to be a "direct" dependency of your crate for it to be accessible.